# Calculate number of event occurences before a particular event and number of specific event in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a data in which i need to specifically calculate the number of other events occurred before a particular event. The sample data is below

[image: Sample]

In the above image there are two PUMP RUN. So what I need to derive is the cumulative number of other events before each PUMP RUN and store in a new column for each ID value. There would be multiple ID value with multiple events along with PUMP RUN event. For example, based on the above image for First occurrence of pump run within that ID value it has to be 5 and for the second occurrence it has to be 3 and so on. Once the ID value changes, the cumulative count needs to restart.

Desired Output

[image: Desired Output]

I tried to do this with the below code however its not getting grouped or partitioned based on the ID value.

```
data['Count'] = data.groupby(data['EventDescription'].str.startswith('Pump RUN').cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
data['EventsCount'] = data.groupby('ID')['Count'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1))
```

Secondly I need to find how many events had the PUMP RUN for each ID value. I was able to find this out with the below code

```
data['PumpRun'] = np.where(data['EventDescription'].str.startswith('Pump RUN'), 1, 0)
data['RunCount'] = data.groupby(['ID']).PumpRun.transform('sum')
```

However I want to know whether there is a simple way to achieve this instead of creating multiple columns for the calculation.

Below is my full code

```
data = pd.read_csv('eventdata.csv')
data.head()
data = data.sort_values(by=["SiteNumber", "SerialNumber","ID","Time"] , ascending = True)
data['Count'] = data.groupby(data['EventDescription'].str.startswith('Pump RUN').cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
data['EventsCount'] = data.groupby('ID')['Count'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1))
data['EventsCount'] = data['EventsCount'].fillna(0)
data.drop(data[data['ID'].eq('')].index, inplace = True)
data['PumpRun'] = np.where(data['EventDescription'].str.startswith('Pump RUN'), 1, 0)
data['RunCount'] = data.groupby(['ID']).PumpRun.transform('sum')
data.to_csv("events_count.csv")
```

Below is the link for the data.

[Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xuhefk06d77txnd/stackoverflow_data.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may at least answer the first part of your question.  The idea is to identify the `Pump RUN` groups with a `cumsum` on a shifted boolean mask.  Then `groupby` on that and the `ID`.  From there use `transform` to create the resulting `EventCount` sub-column (grouped column).  Note the reset across `ID` boundaries.

**Updated to count the events after Pump Run and before the next stop**

```
target_event_phrases = 'Pump RUN|Pump STOP|User STOP|Infusion Complete|Bolus complete'

pump_grp = df['EventDescription'].str.contains(target_event_phrases).cumsum()

dfc = df.assign(EventCount=df.groupby(['ID',pump_grp])['EventDescription'].transform(
           lambda x: ([len(x)-1] if 'Pump RUN' in x.iat[0] else [0]) + [0]*(len(x)-1)
           )
      )
```

**The following is used only to pull out and display sample Run/Stop groups**

```
g = random.choice(pump_grp.unique())
print(f'{g=}')

for i in range(g-2,g+3):
    print(dfc.loc[pg == i,['ID','EventDescription','EventCount']])
    print('--------------------------------------------')
```

**Dataframe Sample Subset**

```
g=126
             ID                       EventDescription  EventCount
469  5983688711                               Pump RUN           3
470  5983688711  Pump rate updated:; - Rate 60.1 mL/hr           0
471  5983688711  Pump rate updated:; - Rate 50.1 mL/hr           0
472  5983688711  Pump rate updated:; - Rate 40.1 mL/hr           0
--------------------------------------------
             ID       EventDescription  EventCount
473  5983688711              Pump STOP           0
474  5983688711  Downstream Occlusion!           0
475  5983688711  Downstream Occl Clr'd           0
--------------------------------------------
             ID                       EventDescription  EventCount
476  5983688711                Pump RUN - Auto-restart           3
477  5983688711  Pump rate updated:; - Rate 35.1 mL/hr           0
478  5983688711  Pump rate updated:; - Rate 30.1 mL/hr           0
479  5983688711  Pump rate updated:; - Rate 25.1 mL/hr           0
--------------------------------------------
             ID   EventDescription  EventCount
480  5983688711  Infusion Complete           0
--------------------------------------------
             ID                    EventDescription  EventCount
481  5983688711                      Pump RUN - KVO           1
482  5983688711  Pump rate updated:; - Rate 1 mL/hr           0
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just wanted to know, say in case if i need to calculate the events count from PUMP Stop to Pump Run, how I must update your code. Currently we have found from Pump Run to Stop. In case if I need to find the events in vice versa? I tried changing the code provided by you but it throws index error.

Comment: I sort of feel like the above code counts from Pump RUN to Pump RUN not taking Pump STOP into account.  Maybe it was implied.  Just trying to understand what you want.  So then the event count would be reported on the Pump Stop line?  And that would be the number of events since the last Pump RUN?  So on line 142 above it would be 1?   And 146 would be 0?  And is User STOP the same as a Pump STOP?

Comment: Yes. Basically I want to count the number of events from Pump Stop to Pump Run in the same manner that we did. For Example 142 has Pump Stop and 145 has Pump Run. So need to calculate the number of events from 143 to 145. Both Pump Stop and User Stop are same.

Comment: How do you want to count in the case where there are two or more `Pump RUN`s without an intervening `Pump STOP`?  For example, line 888 has `User STOP`, then 890 has `Pump RUN` and then 892 has `Pump RUN - KVO`.

Comment: Both Pump Run and Infusion Complete can be treated as same.  Once we have a Complete event, the rest of the data after that will be ignored. Pump Stop/User Stop/Infusion Complete all are treated as Stop. So I need to calculate the number of events from stop to run

Comment: I updated my answer to implement my understanding of the stop-to-run-count use case.

Comment: Thaks it worked. One more thing. The event values are getting calculated from bottom to up. What to do for calculating from top to bottom.

Comment: Not sure exactly what that means.  Give me some examples with some specific line numbers like you did above.

Comment: For example, would line 140 be 1?

Comment: For Example, RowNumber 140 has the counts ranging from Row 118 till 139. Actually, Row number 140 has to count the events after 140 and not before 140. So 140 will have 1 as 142 has PUMP Stop instead of 12

Comment: I updated the answer to address

Comment: JCH - Just a quick question how to change the code to find the date difference between instead of count. Currently the code counts for the number of events between the two but what to do to fid the date difference